# Does Windows 8 OEM comes with Japanese support?

Tags: windows-8, language, oem, japanese

I would like to buy a laptop with Windows 8 OEM, and use is to read and write Japanese.

Adding most languages is as easy as adding their input modes. However, in previous versions of windows (XP and Vista, I don't know about 7), Japanese did not appear on the list of supported languages until I installed additional support for east Asian languages.
Installing that package required the original Windows disk - which I will not have for an OEM version.

Will this be a problem in Windows 8?

Comment: For the record - I called Microsoft supports and they said it should be OK, but they weren't confident enough.

Comment: Only Windows 8 Professional has the ability to install most language packs.  Since  Japanese is a major language there is a good chance it will require the Professional edition of Windows 8.  Just the language pack documentation to determine which version of Windows 8 is required.

Comment: @Ramhound - I think a "language pack" is used to change the Windows UI, that is not what I'm asking. I want to have Windows in English, but be able to read and write Japanese.

Comment: @Kobi Easiest way to test.. go in store and see if you can add japanese keyboard in-store. It may need admin right to complete the installation, but at least you can see if the option to add Japanese is listed or not. Just found this --> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/language

Comment: @Kobi - You still need the language pack.  There are two elements to a language pack.  One changes the interface language the other adds what you want.

Comment: @Darius - That's a good idea. They don't have physical shops, but I guess I can find someone who does. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a bad question for SU? Any pointers? I searched and couldn't find an answer, and *I* think it is clear.

Comment: @Kobi - My downvote was issued becaused the solution is to install the Japanese language pack which is well documented, which leads me to believe, there wasn't enough research done on the subject. You even seem to be aware of what language packs are generally used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure Japanese input mode without installing anything, and even without being connected to the internet.
I tried it on two computers at a shop and the one I bought.

Answer (score 2):

I've [installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607) Japanese language support on both my English Windows 8 and my Swedish one. And both times I've downloaded a language pack from Microsoft.

But it does it automatically when you add the language if memory serves.

You will have to install the Japanese language pack through the control panel and your operating system can be any language.

[Japanese Language Pack](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win8)

Comment: As Darius suggested, I went ahead and confirmed that in a computer shop - I checked on two computers with no internet connection, and it just worked (one of them was similar to the one I'm looking for). I think you can roll back the edit - it doesn't seem like the language pack is required.

Answer (score 1):

Though Windows 8 support Japanese language, you are able to download language pack from Microsoft and install it. Refer [Microsoft kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607) and [installation procedure](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/downloads/install-languages-with-windows-update)